# MySQL Return ONLY results that match criteria

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to select only items in the database that match the exact criteria, in this case I need the item to be both active and on tap.  This then populates a carousel and the arrows navigate to the item by ID.

```
/* mySql  code */
if ($select = $db -> prepare("SELECT id, name, type, active, abv, ibu, og, hops, color, description, growlers, tap, cans, bottles, image FROM beers WHERE tap = 'Yes' AND (active = 'Yes') AND (id = ?)"))
{
    $select -> bind_param('s', $_GET['id']);
    $select -> execute();
    $select -> bind_result($id, $name, $type, $active, $abv, $ibu, $og, $hops, $color, $description, $growlers, $tap, $cans, $bottles, $image);
    $select -> fetch();
    $select -> close();
}

/* carousel  code */
<a id="prev" class="controls" href="./?page=tapbeer&id=<?php echo $_GET['id'] - 1; ?>">
 <i class="fal fa-angle-left"></i>
</a>
<a id="next" class="controls" href="./?page=tapbeer&id=<?php echo $_GET['id'] + 1; ?>">
  <i class="fal fa-angle-right"></i>
</a>
```

I only want the next ID that is available matching the criteria, not the next ID in sequence.

For instance, we have 5 items, three are active and two are on tap

```
+-------+-------+--------+------+
| id    | name  | active | tap  |
+-------+-------+--------+------+
| 1     | beer1 | Y      | Y    |
+-------+-------+--------+------+
| 2     | beer2 | Y      | N    |
+-------+-------+--------+------+
| 3     | beer3 | N      | N    |
+-------+-------+--------+------+
| 4     | beer4 | Y      | Y    |
+-------+-------+--------+------+
| 5     | beer5 | M      | N    |
+-------+-------+--------+------+
```

I only want beer1 and beer4 to display in the carousel.

The problem I keep running into is all IDs scroll through, and show empty in the carousel because they do not match the criteria because we look at the ID and either add or subtract 1 to get the next ID in sequence.

Comment: It's easier to do in MySQL 8.x. Are you using MySQL 5.x or 8.x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Queries to get next and previous value are:

```
SELECT id
FROM beers 
WHERE tap = 'Yes' AND active = 'Yes' AND id > ?
ORDER BY id ASC
LIMIT 1

SELECT id
FROM beers 
WHERE tap = 'Yes' AND active = 'Yes' AND id < ?
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

`?` should be replaced with current id.

Execute these queries and get `id`s required for your next/previous links.

Basically it is:

```
if ($select = $db -> prepare("SELECT id, name, type, active, abv, ibu, og, hops, color, description, growlers, tap, cans, bottles, image FROM beers WHERE tap = 'Yes' AND (active = 'Yes') AND (id = ?)"))
{
    $select -> bind_param('s', $_GET['id']);
    $select -> execute();
    $select -> bind_result($id, $name, $type, $active, $abv, $ibu, $og, $hops, $color, $description, $growlers, $tap, $cans, $bottles, $image);
    $select -> fetch();
    $select -> close();


    $nextId = $db->prepare('query_1');
    $nextId -> bind_param('s', $_GET['id']);
    $nextId -> execute();
    $nextId -> bind_result($next_id);
    $nextId -> fetch();
    $nextId -> close();

    $prevId = $db->prepare('query_2');
    $prevId -> bind_param('s', $_GET['id']);
    $prevId -> execute();
    $prevId -> bind_result($prev_id);
    $prevId -> fetch();
    $prevId -> close();
}

/* carousel  code */
<a id="prev" class="controls" href="./?page=tapbeer&id=<?php echo $prev_id; ?>">
 <i class="fal fa-angle-left"></i>
</a>
<a id="next" class="controls" href="./?page=tapbeer&id=<?php echo $next_id; ?>">
  <i class="fal fa-angle-right"></i>
</a>
```

Comment: Sorry u_mulder you lost me.  I understand what you have there, but how does this all go together with my original code?

Comment: Execute this queries in your code, each query wiil give you id of either __next__ or __previous__ record. Then use them in your links.

Comment: I know I am asking much, but can you put it together as you see it?  When I did it within my code, the ID's return were still sequential of all whether they met the criteria

Comment: See the update, `query_1`, `query_2` are queries in my answer.

Comment: Thanks, but that created a fatal error "Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean"  UPDATE: I fixed the fatal error, used the queries directly in the 'query_1', 'query_2' statements and now returns blank result for previous and next

Comment: You need `fetch()` after `bind_result()`

Comment: What is the `var_dump` of `$next/prev_id` vars? Also check that you have data in tables. Try to run raw queries on mysql and see it there are results.

Comment: @Paul Spiegel fetch() returned Warning: mysqli_stmt::fetch(): Couldn't fetch mysqli_stmt

Comment: @u_mulder  var_dump of $next/prev_id both returned NULL.  Tables have data, I know because it populates the page with what I expect, just not grabbing the next or previous ID

Comment: What do you see when you execute raw queries (in console or phpmyadmin) on the table?

Comment: @u_mulder my query shows all data I expect to return, 18 rows of full data

Comment: We're talking about queries I suggest in my answer. What do __they__ show if you execute'em in console/phpmyadmin?

Comment: Does my solution help or not?